# .bash_functions: Calling a function from another one

Tags: bash

I have the following two functions defined in my `.bash_functions` (which gets sourced into `.bashrc`):

```
up() {
  if (($# == 0)); then
    cd ..
  else
    for basename; do
      local result=$(_foo)
      echo $result
      cd $result
    done
  fi
}

_foo() {
  echo ${PWD%/$1/*}/$basename
}
```

While I can execute `_foo`, when i execute `up`, up doesn't seem to know `_foo`. Am I doing something wrong here, or is this just not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does "know" `_foo`, but you don't pass a parameter to `_foo`, so probably that's causing the confusion.

Comment: It sees `basename` just fine. Variables are global unless declared local. The problem is that `_foo()` expects an argument (`$1`) and isn't getting passed one. This is what your example is actually illustrating, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Bash scripts are executed sequentially. In your case, `_foo()` could be defined before `up()` and everything should work fine.

Comment: It doesn't matter what order they're defined as long as they're called after they're defined. `up() { _foo; }; _foo() { echo "bar"; }; up` works just fine.